# Duplicate Declaration Error on the same line

Tags: puppet, devops

I am using puppet to create a module to apply other manifests within other modules that will be on every one of my nodes as I do not want to repeatedly type out every resource manually. This manifest will be included in other classes that go on different nodes and will be called as a reference.

```
windowscommoncomponents::install {'windows-common-components':}
```

I am coming across a 'Duplicate Declaration Error' when testing the module. And it says that the error is on the same line in the same manifest.

```
# Defined type to install common components to all windows nodes.

define windowscommoncomponents::install {
  include notepadplusplus
  include vs2015redist
  include windowsutils
  include windowskbs

  # Install Notepad++
  $_notepadplusplus_version = '7.3.3'
  notepadplusplus::install { "notepadplusplus-${_notepadplusplus_version}":
    version => $_notepadplusplus_version
  }

  # Install the 2015 redist
  vs2015redist::install { 'vs2015-redist':
  }

  #Configure the Puppet service to start automatically.
  windowsutils::configurepuppetservice { 'configure-puppet-service':
  }

  #Configure the Windows Event Logs.
  windowsutils::configureeventlog { 'event-log-configuration':
  }

  # Install the Windows Security patch CVE-2019-0708.
  windowskbs::cve20190708 { 'install-cve-2019-0708':
  }
}
```

I expect the manifest to install Notepad++, vs2015redist, the security patch, configure the puppet service and to configure the windows event logs. The error that I get is:

```
Warning: Config file C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/hiera.yaml not found,
using Hiera defaults
Error: Duplicate declaration: Windowskbs::Cve20190708[install-cve-2019-0708] is
already declared in file Y:/Puppet/windowscommoncomponents/manifests/install.pp:
29; cannot redeclare at Y:/Puppet/windowscommoncomponents/manifests/install.pp:2
9 on node win-m6ecv2ojt53.localdomain
Error: Duplicate declaration: Windowskbs::Cve20190708[install-cve-2019-0708] is
already declared in file Y:/Puppet/windowscommoncomponents/manifests/install.pp:
29; cannot redeclare at Y:/Puppet/windowscommoncomponents/manifests/install.pp:2
9 on node win-m6ecv2ojt53.localdomain
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your defined resource type being declared more than once per catalog?

Comment: ... and is there a reason why it shouldn't be a class, instead?